# Repeating Regex Match Sequence

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

My strings are formatted like this `[label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah ...` repeating any number of times.

The regex I thought would work (and that seems to work in other regex engines) is `^(\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*))+` however this only matches the first `[label] blah blah blah` section with matches:

1. the whole string
2. [label] blah blah blah
3. label
4. blah blah blah

If I use `^([^\[]*)(\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*))(\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*)).*` I can match 2 sequences but how would I get this to work for x number of sequences? Can I change the regex engine c++ uses?

full code for completeness:

```
int main() {
//    const regex match_string(R"((\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*))(\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*)).*)");
    const regex match_string(R"((\[([^\]]*)\]([^\[]*))+)");
    string line = "[label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah";
    smatch matches;
    bool res = regex_match(line, matches, match_string);
    if (res) {
        for (const auto &match : matches) {
            cout << match << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "no match" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: For such a simple parse you don’t need a regular expression. Just use `std::string::find(‘[‘)` and `std::find(‘]’)`.

Comment: Your regex matches as expected, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/eHrb0J/1). What results do you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would expect it to make a match for each label and word set, not just one match on the last one like your link shows. The goal is to be able to extract each label and it's corresponding set of words

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/BsMU93 ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes like that

Answer (score 3):

Based on Pete Becker's comment, and my best guess as to what you actually want to achieve, you might want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line = "[label1] blah blah blah [label2] blah blah blah [label3] blah blah blah [label4] blah blah blah";
    size_t start_pos = 0;

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        size_t lbr = line.find ('[', start_pos);
        std::string words = line.substr (start_pos,  lbr - start_pos);
        std::cout << ": " << words << std::endl;
        if (lbr == std::string::npos)
            break;
        size_t rbr = line.find (']', lbr);
        if (rbr == std::string::npos)
            break;
        std::string label = line.substr (lbr + 1, rbr - lbr - 1);
        std::cout << label;
        start_pos = rbr + 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
: 
label1:  blah blah blah 
label2:  blah blah blah 
label3:  blah blah blah 
label4:  blah blah blah
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aF8JdQ0TTuxJwOtN)

Comment: Yes that's almost (except for extracting the words also so I put in an edit for that) exactly the functionality I need. It doesn't exactly answer the question but solves the problem thank you and Pete Becker.

Answer (score 2):

You may tokenize the string into those strings inside square brackets and those not matching the bracket regex using the `\s*\[([^\][]+)\]\s*` regex:

```
std::regex rx(R"(\s*\[([^\][]+)\]\s*)");
string line = "[label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah [label] blah blah blah";
std::sregex_token_iterator iter(line.begin(), line.end(), rx, {-1, 1});
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::remove_copy_if(iter, std::sregex_token_iterator(), 
                std::back_inserter(tokens),
                [](std::string const &s) { return s.empty(); });
```

Then,

```
for (auto & p : tokens) std::cout <<"'"<< p <<"'"<< std::endl;
```

prints

```
'label'
'blah blah blah'
'label'
'blah blah blah'
'label'
'blah blah blah'
'label'
'blah blah blah'
```

Note that `\s*\[([^\][]+)\]\s*` matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fcHd26/1).

The `{-1, 1}` argument passed to `std::sregex_token_iterator()` tells the regex engine to extract non-matched strings (`-1`) and those substrings captured into Group 1 (`1`).